# Travel from Dublin to Macau

Tags: visas, air-travel, china, hong-kong, macau

I am a Romanian national and I will travel from Dublin to Macau and I have 2 flight options:

**First option:**

```
EI 650  09JUN   09JUN   DUB Dublin          FRA Frankfurt/Main  0700    1010
CA 432  09JUN   10JUN   FRA Frankfurt/Main  CTU Chengdu         1415    0605
CA5467  10JUN   10JUN   CTU Chengdu         MFM Macau           0835    1105


CA5454  16JUN   16JUN   MFM Macau           PEK Beijing         0710    1015
CA 933  16JUN   16JUN   PEK Beijing         CDG Paris CDG       1335    1840
EI 529  16JUN   16JUN   CDG Paris CDG       DUB Dublin          2155    2235
```

**Second option:**

```
KL 936  09JUN   09JUN   DUB Dublin          AMS Amsterdam       1320    1555
KL 887  09JUN   10JUN   AMS Amsterdam       HKG Hong Kong       1720    1020

KL 888  19JUN   19JUN   HKG Hong Kong       AMS Amsterdam       1220    1820
KL 939  19JUN   19JUN   AMS Amsterdam       DUB Dublin          2120    2200
```

For the first option I need to make 2 stops.

For the second option I need to take a ferry from the Hong Kong airport to Macau.

Which one is the easiest?

I want to take the second option, but should I be concerned about the time of the flight in case of the return of the second option? It leaves at 12:20, but it could be the case that there is no ferry in the morning from Macau.

Answer (score 4):

According to [this website](https://www.turbojet.com.hk/en/routing-sailing-schedule/hk-airport-macau/sailing-schedule-fares.aspx), there are ferries from Macau to Hong Kong International Airport every day at 7:15am and 9:30am. The trip takes 70 minutes and costs 254 Hong Kong dollars (about US$ 33). 9:30am might be cutting it fine, but the 7:15 sailing will give you plenty of time.

Answer (score 4):

In practical terms, Macau is essentially a regional airport. It is very small compared to Hong Kong.

[TurboJET](https://www.turbojet.com.hk/en/routing-sailing-schedule/hk-airport-macau/sailing-schedule-fares.aspx) has two morning sailing directly to the airport.  If neither of those suite you, there is direct service to Hong Kong every 15 minutes.  From there, you can walk ~1km to the Airport Express train.